# D3js plugin for Fisheye Distortion not appearing in Tree Layout & Sunburst Partition

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree, fisheye, sunburst-diagram

I'm trying to implement fisheye plugin for d3js in [Tree Layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550) & [Sunburst Partition](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063423). The example given is for force layout. I tried the way they have mentioned for  [fisheye](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/fisheye). But I feel Like there is some layout based support, due to which it's not supported by most/some other layouts. But I'm not sure my analysis is correct or not.

So I need some suggestions/hint on this "How to achieve Fisheye distortion for magnifying glass effect".

Can any body help me on this???

Comment: Could you tell us what you have tried? This is a very general question.

Comment: i tried somthing like http://jsfiddle.net/g88S7/. but not getting node.each next to line 59. here only m missing somthing.